# [Laravel]419 HTTP Error not casued by csrf token missing

Tags: laravel, post, csrf

419 HTTP Error was occured when I try to login after I installed laravel/ui.
In order to resolve this issue, I tried the following methods though I haven't solved yet.

1. I checked resources/views/auth/login.blade.php and confirmed
   @csrf is placed right after form tab.
2. I found cookie setting on browser's setting so I changed it to be allowed in all situations.

I dont know how I would investigate or resolve it.
So I'm glad if you share any advices or solutions.

Here are the server environment that I installed Laravel Framework.

AWS Amazon linux 2

Laravel Framework 9.50.2

mysql  Ver 8.0.32 for Linux on x86_64

PHP 8.0.27 (cli) (built: Jan  3 2023 16:17:26)

Comment: Does this work when running locally?

Comment: No. I dont tried it locally. How do i try it locally? Is there any refferences to try?

Comment: what session driver  are you using in your .env file ? It may have something to do with misconfiguration of the session, try using the SESSION_DRIVER=file and check if it works

Comment: At first, I saw SESSION_DRIVER=file in .env though it didnt work. So I changed it to SESSION_DRIVER=database and create a table for session. but still 419 error appears.

Comment: I found out where this error comes from.
Just the cache on client side were left. I'm confused with 'php artisan cache:clear' which cleans up caches on the server side.
So what I did is to just reload a page.

Thanks,